# Passing data between two Method in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(tempUser userDetails)
        {

            temp.Name = userDetails.Name;
            temp.Pass= userDetails.Pass;

            db.tempUsers.Add(temp);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (true)
            {
                await SendNotification();
                return RedirectToAction("NotificationUser", "SignUp", new { tempUser = userDetails});
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AAA");
            }
        }
```

I have a controller like above. How can I pass all result of `temp` `(temp.Name, temp.Pass ...)` into `SignUp()` method in the same controller `NotificationUser`.

Comment: `TempData` can be used to pass the data

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for help. I just edited my question.

Comment: If you're trying to pass the data through the query string parameters then you'll need to split tempUser into name and pass. If `pass` is a password then you probably don't want to send it over the query string at all. In that case, `TempData` is what you want.